# quartz cronExpression config issue

Tags: spring, timer, quartz

I am using spring + quartz for schedule a job which need run every 22 mins.and configured as below. but the job start the hour point(Sharp) too. (running time like : 12:00, 12:22, 12:44, 13:00(why?), 13:22,13:44. even configured to 0 */22 * * * ? or 0 0/22 * * * ?, it's too.

```
<bean id="cronTrigger_LogBackupManager" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail_LogBackupManager" />
    <property name="cronExpression">
        <value>0 /22 * * * ?</value>    <!-- each 22 min -->
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Doesn't "/22" or "0/22" mean 0, 22, 44, ... so on ?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this but can you just try "22/22" on minutes ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html#format)

> / - used to specify increments. For example, “0/15” in the seconds
>   field means “the seconds 0, 15, 30, and 45”. And “5/15” in the seconds
>   field means “the seconds 5, 20, 35, and 50”.

Therefore I believe using "22/22" on minutes should do the trick. P.S I haven't tried this. Let me know it this doesn't work.

Comment: with "22/22", it only run at the 22nd, 44th mins of each hour... but thank you all the same.

Comment: So your expectation is to run it continuously increasing like "22, 44, 06, 28, 50, 12, 34, 56, 18, 40, 2, 24, 46, 8, 30, 52, 14, 36, 58, 20, 42, 4, 26, 48, 10, 32, 54, 18, 40" in this sequence in minutes?

Comment: Thanks for your great help. but i am using spring with Quartz supported framework. i need at least update to fix it currently by just update the cronExpression value. And Yes. expectation is to run it continuously increasing like "22, 44, 06, 28, 50, 12, 34, 56, 18, 40 ..."

Comment: @Paul Please let me know if you get this to work. It's quite interesting. Cheers!

Comment: sure.i will paste the solution here once it works well.